# Getting sub-menu items and echo

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the sub-menu items of the active page im on and echo them out with a wordpress query. I've figured out to do this for post types for for menu's im struggling a little. Here's the post types version i'm using.

```
  <div class="container">
<div class="grid mb-10 mt-10 w-full text-white sm:grid-cols-3 gap-4">

<?php
        // WP_Query arguments
        wp_nav_menu( array(
          'menu'        => 'Menu Name',
          'sub_menu'    => true,
          'show_parent' => true
        ) );
        // The Query
        $services = new WP_Query( $args );
        // The Loop
        if ( $services->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $services->have_posts() ) {
        $services->the_post();
    ?>

  <div class="p-5 bg-gray-300">

    <h3 class="pt-5 pb-0 mb-0 capitalize"><a>THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO ECHO THE TITLE</h3></a>

    <button class="btn btn-blue mt-5 mb-5"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?> ">read more</a></button>

  </div>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php }}?>

</div>
```

Comment: I see what you want, bu what if we already are on a submenu page ? Do you need to display siblings menu items ?

Comment: I think that you need to read this post, it works pretty well : https://christianvarga.com/how-to-get-submenu-items-from-a-wordpress-menu-based-on-parent-or-sibling/

Comment: I think this may help explain - https://imgur.com/a/MHGqFT2 - I am currently on the page "steel fabs" and i want to echo the remaining sub pages into the 6 boxes at the bottom of the page.

Comment: So the previous link i gave you is what you need. Tell me if you don't understand it. But you simply have to copy the hook in your functions.php and then call wp_nav_menu with the right parameters at the place of your six blocks.

Comment: Cheers @AlexisVandepitte - the code works It's just pulling through as a ul / li menu into the code. How would I go about echo'ing the title. / permalink into the structure i already have? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: You should have the link inside the li, with the menu title. Don't you ? Edit your answer with your new code and the html result please.

Comment: See updated code @AlexisVandepitte

Comment: Well with the solution i gave you, you can't use custom HTML, except if you create a custom nav walker. You can find a good tutorial here : https://www.ibenic.com/how-to-create-wordpress-custom-menu-walker-nav-menu-class/

Comment: I'm searching for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your functions.php file put this function :

```
function display_related_menu_pages() {
    // Get all menu items
    // replace "Menu Name" by your menu name or id
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('Menu Name');

    // Get the current item (current page)
    $current_item = false;
    foreach($menu_items as $item) {
        if((int)$item->object_id === get_the_id()) {
            $current_item = $item;
        }
    }

    // Get the parent ID
    $parent_id = false;
    if($current_item->menu_item_parent != 0) {
        $parent_id = $current_item->menu_item_parent;
    }else {
        $parent_id = $current_item->ID;
    }

    // Prepare items to display
    $items_to_display = [];

    // Get only items that have the parent_id or the item that is the parent_id
    foreach($menu_items as $item) {
        if(($parent_id == $item->ID || $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent) &&  $item->ID !== $current_item->ID  ) {
            $items_to_display[] = $item;
        }
    }

    // Display items
    foreach($items_to_display as $item) : 
    ?>
        <div class="p-5 bg-gray-300">

            <h3 class="pt-5 pb-0 mb-0 capitalize"><a><?php echo $item->title; ?></h3></a>

            <button class="btn btn-blue mt-5 mb-5"><a href="<?php echo $item->url; ?>"><?php _e('read more', 'your-theme-text-domain'); ?></a></button>

        </div>

    <?php 
    endforeach;
}
```

Then in your template juste call the function where you want it to display

```
display_related_menu_pages();
```

You can also have the function to only return the menu items like this:

```
function get_related_menu_pages() {
    // Get all menu items
    // replace "Menu Name" by your menu name or id
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('Menu Name');

    // Get the current item (current page)
    $current_item = false;
    foreach($menu_items as $item) {
        if((int)$item->object_id === get_the_id()) {
            $current_item = $item;
        }
    }

    // Get the parent ID
    $parent_id = false;
    if($current_item->menu_item_parent != 0) {
        $parent_id = $current_item->menu_item_parent;
    }else {
        $parent_id = $current_item->ID;
    }

    // Prepare items to display
    $items_to_display = [];

    // Get only items that have the parent_id or the item that is the parent_id
    foreach($menu_items as $item) {
        if(($parent_id == $item->ID || $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent) &&  $item->ID !== $current_item->ID  ) {
            $items_to_display[] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $items_to_display;
}
```

and handle the display in your template :

```
$related_pages = get_related_menu_pages();

// Display items
foreach($related_pages as $item) : 
    ?>
        <div class="p-5 bg-gray-300">

            <h3 class="pt-5 pb-0 mb-0 capitalize"><a><?php echo $item->title; ?></h3></a>

            <button class="btn btn-blue mt-5 mb-5"><a href="<?php echo $item->url; ?>"><?php _e('read more', 'your-theme-text-domain'); ?></a></button>

        </div>

    <?php 
endforeach;
```